# Issue to install tor browser on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking

I've just installed Ubuntu 22.04 without a problem. When I tried to install the tor package, I get the error message, "Tor Browser requires a CPU with SSE2 support. Exiting". When I try installing from the repository, I get the error message, "No tor browser-launcher package is available".

Many thanks for your help

Comment: So does the CPU support SSE2? What is the CPU?

Answer (score -1):

The error message is plain: your processor, whatever it is, doesn't support [SSE2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE2), and the tor browser requires one that does. You cannot run tor on that computer.